# How to build a simple dollar/euro react currency converter with fixed conversion ratio?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

For an exercise, I need to build a very simple currency converter that converts currency only from dollars to euro and vice versa with set rates (0.91 / 1.09).
I want to be my App.js file as modular as possible. Also, I want to use hooks (not class components)

My file structure:

```
src
├── components (Holds all components)
│   ├── InputDollar.js (gets Dollar Input)
│   ├── InputEuro.js (gets Euro Input)
│   ├── Button.js (triggers conversion)
│   └── Converter.js (Converts Dollar into Euro or vice versa)
├── App.js (renders all components)
└── Index.js (eventually exports to html "root" id)
```

I guess it would be too long to post all the code I have so far here, but I share a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-morning-l3y1e?fontsize=14

**I think the Inputs and the Button is fine. What is most probably flawed is the Converter Component - which I share below - (as I got confused how to pass in Inputs and how to write the correct syntax in the if statement) and the App Component as I have troubles to display the result upon button Click.**

Converter.js

```
import React from "react";
import InputDollar from "./InputDollar"
import InputEuro from "./InputEuro"


function ConvertedValue() {

  let converted = function() {
    if(<InputDollar>!="") {
      ConvertedValue = (<InputDollar />* 0.9)
    } else if (<InputEuro>!="") {
      ConvertedValue = (<InputEuro />* 1.1)
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {converted}
    </div>
  );
}

export default ConvertedValue;
```

Can you help me with this exercise and - where possible - comment out the major functionalities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would approach adapting your existing code:

1) One `<Input>` component to serve both causes. It accepts both a type and label as well as your `handleChange` method.

```
function Input(props) {

  const { label, type, handleChange } = props;

  function onChange(event) {

    // Pass in the type and value
    handleChange(type, event.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <label>{label}</label>
      <input onChange={onChange} type="number" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

2) In your `<App>` component:

```
function App() {

  // Have one state for the converted value
  const [ convertedValue, setConvertedValue ] = useState(0);

  // Then, when `handleChange` is called, just choose between the
  // input type, and set the state
  function handleChange(type, value) {
    if (type === 'euro') setConvertedValue(value * 1.1);
    if (type === 'dollar') setConvertedValue(value * 0.9);
  }

  return (
    <div>

      // Using the Input component pass in the type, label, and handleChange
      // for the dollar and euro
      <Input type="dollar" label="Dollar" handleChange={handleChange} />
      <Input type="euro" label="Euro" handleChange={handleChange} />

      // Then you can keep the updated converted value here
      <div>{convertedValue}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Hope this is useful.

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-kare-sqcli)

Comment: Hey Andy, thx. That's very useful with the comments and very close to what I want to achieve. 

The missing piece would be indeed a button component that triggers converted Value to be displayed upon click. How would this look like?

Comment: Depends what you want the button to do. I've updated my sandbox to show an example of it toggling between showing/hiding the value in the div.

Comment: Thx ... I admit, the button wasn't thought through. I wanted the button to show an alert message saying "x € are y $" (or vice versa). 

Re-thinking it, your first approach was probably the better way to go about it (without button). Forgot to fork it though

Comment: Now that I think about it, what would have made your first approach best is that it displays the converted value below (as you did) but with two adaptations: 1) it adds the currency to which it was converted i.e. if dollar was entered it adds Euro after the converted value and vice versa. 2) entering a value in input 1 automatically deletes entries from input 2 as it gets confusing otherwise which input is converted

Comment: I've switched it using two states (for convenience) and no button: https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-kare-sqcli